# How to upload all .html files to a remote server using FTP and preserving file structure?

Tags: python, networking, scripting, ftp

I have edited about 100 html files locally, and now I want to push them to my live server, which I can only access via ftp.

The HTML files are in many different directories, but hte directory structure on the remote machine is the same as on the local machine.

How can I recursively descend from my top-level directory ftp-ing all of the .html files to the corresponding directory/filename on the remote machine?

Thanks!

Comment: If I were you, I would use an FTP client like FireFTP or GFTP. The code to do this is kind of twisty, and unless there's some special reason you need to write code for this, using a specialized client could save you a lot of headaches. (Another thing you could try is politely asking the sysadmin to give you SSH access for SFTP, or install rsync, or something. FTP is quite insecure and inefficient.)

Comment: In order to suggest the best way, what platform are you using on both your local machine, and the remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in Python (rather than using other pre-packaged existing tools), you can use [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk) to read everything in the local subtree, and [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html?highlight=ftp#module-ftplib) to perform all the FTP operations.  In particular, [storbinary](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html?highlight=ftp#ftplib.FTP.storbinary) is the method you'll usually use to transfer entire files without line-end conversions (storlines if you *do* want line-end conversions, for files that are text, not binary, and that you know need such treatment).

Answer (score 0):

umm, maybe by pressing F5 in mc for linux or total commander for windows?

Answer (score 0):

After searching PyPI, I found ftptool (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftptool/0.4.2). Its `mirror_to_remote` method could be what you need. I don't have an FTP server handy, though, so I couldn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a mac, you can try cyberduck.  It's good for syncing remote directory structures via ftp.